# git push showing "Everything up-to-date" but compare shows differences

Tags: git, github, version-control

Hello I have this problem I contribute to an opensource repo. Each time I work from the master branch even if what am working on is not for the master branch usually when the code is merged I will pull upstream (The original repo) to get my master branch back to normal. This has caused me problems recently after creating some changes and committed I pulled upstream to get back at the same level with the original repository when I push to my cloned repo it says everything is up to date. But When I do compare on github it shows differences with upstream.
I have tried

1. git checkout master
2. pulling upstream again committing and then
   pushing again

that did not  work!
I tried checking out commits

```
 1. git checkout HEAD~5 
 2. git pull upstream master 
 3. git add   
 4. git commit 
 5. git push
```

Did not work still.

I will also like to know a simple way to create a quick-fix branch for every issue and avoid doing everything from my master branch thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I pulled upstream to get back at the same level with the original repository

If you want to replace your cloned/origin repo *master* with the *upstream/master*
then one way is to reset your *origin/master* with *upstream/master*.

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard upstream/master      # local/master = upstream/master

$ git push -f origin master             # force push to origin/master
```

Now, there should be no difference between *origin/master* and *upstream/master*

Note: force (-f) push will replace your *origin/master* by your *local/master = upstream/master* history.

---

> I will also like to know a simple way to create a quick-fix branch for every issue and avoid doing everything from my master branch

You can create and checkout a new branch from upstream/master locally directly.

```
# no matter in which branch you are now!
$ git fetch upstream
$ git checkout -b quick-fix upstream/master  # chekcout to 'quick-fix' branch with the same history of 'upstream/master'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

To make your `origin/master` is same with `upstream/master` needs force pull/push (maybe upstream/master changed the history commits). So before that, you need to push the branches which checked out from your local `master` branch to `origin` so that changes on these branch will not lost. Then sync `origin/master` with `upstream/master` with below steps:

```
git checkout master
git pull -f upstream master
git reset --hard upstream/master
git push -f origin master
```

Now `origin/master` is sync with `upstream/master`. You can double check with below commands:

```
git log origin/master..upstream/master
git log upstream/master..origin/master
```

If both of the two commands have no output, that means `origin/master` and `upstream/master` at the same level (synchronized).

Comment: Thanks for your answer its pretty much the same like the first.